# Register user-defined functions in excel addin automatically

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a macro which registers my user-defined functions, places them in custom categories and supplies descriptions, called `AddUDFsToCategory`. This macro is placed in a module in an add-in I have installed. However, for the UDFs to become registered, I have to run the macro manually every time I open Excel.

I want this macro to run when I open Excel, even though no workbook is open. I tried to use the Workbook_AddinInstall in the "ThisWorkbook" section of the addin,

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
    AddUDFsToCategory
End Sub
```

but that doesn't seem to achieve anything.

If I try to use it with Workbook_open,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AddUDFsToCategory
End Sub
```

I get:

> "Run-time error '1004': Cannot edit a macro on a hidden workbook. Unhide the workbook using the Unhide command."

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to register it through the Excel Options menu.

**First, go to options then click on Add-Ins:**

[image][image]

**From This point, you should be able to manage your add-ins by clicking Go.**

[image]

---

## You should also try managing your Add-Ins within the VBE itself.

Open VBE and Click `Add-ins`:

[image]

Here you will find the Add-ins manager. Select your add-in and ensure that the checkbox that says *"Load on Startup"* is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, the addin itself is already registered through Options > Add-ins. And the udfs themselves work fine. It's just how to automatically run the AddUDFsToCategory macro that I can't get to work. Strangely, I cannot see my add-in from the Add-ins manager in VBE.

Comment: @LarsS Can you try creating a reference to the workbook within VBE? `Tools > References`.

Comment: @LarsS Open VBE, Click Tools, References, Browse. Then navigate to your folder containing your addin in question. You may have to click the dropdown box next to the filename and select All Files

Comment: From which project should I reference it? If I try to reference it from the relevant xlam file, the workbook only becomes self-referenced and I get an error message saying "Name conflicts with existing module, project or object library."

Comment: In the VBE project explorer where you can see all your modules, try renaming the module containing your addin (likely `Module1`) to something else, click save, then try again.

Comment: You may also rename the VBA project as well (and click save). You also would do this within the project explorer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and see if it leads anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to get around this error is to force Excel to have a workbook open when I'm trying to register the UDFs.

```
Sub AddUDFsToCategory()
   Dim wbkTemp As Excel.Workbook

   If Application.ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then
      Set wbkTemp = Application.Workbooks.Add
   End If

   '/--------------------------------------------\
   ' Code to register your User Defined Functions
   '\--------------------------------------------/

   If Not wbkTemp Is Nothing Then
      wbkTemp.Close False
   End If
End Sub
```